# document.querySelector with AppleScript / Safari

Tags: safari, applescript, javascript, javascript-automation

I need a script to open each tab in safari when I get "valueIneed" from an internal website

here is the HTML tag

```
<td class="orderDetails">


    <p class="details">
        (My Certificate)
    </p>
```

here is what I tried this but this is failing

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "
        var forgiveStatus = document.querySelector('class[details\"(My Certificate).innerHTML;
        " in current tab of first window
    set checkvalue to (do JavaScript "theStatus;" in current tab of first window) as string
end tell
```

for more information it's could have multiple instance of the same tag, and I need to open each one in a new tab, or even better click on them one after one

Comment: there's something strange with `querySelector` function. It looks to me that there's lack of closing bracket there. Here are examples of the proper usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: In that case to get the value of the `<p class="details">` you need to call `document.querySelector(".details").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed any quotes or brackets. You need the following four characters.

```
var theStatus = document.querySelector('class[details="(valueIneed)"]')
                                                                   ^^^^
```

This is now syntactically correct JavaScript. I still doubt it'll do what you need, <strike>but without seeing the DOM of the page you're running this on and a full problem description I can't say for sure.</strike>

Given the update to your question with a snippet of HTML, the code you're trying won't work. To get the inner HTML of the element, use the following JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("td.orderDetails .details").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but then I always have a syntax error "Expected end of line but found "(".

Comment: @Kevin Then something else is seriously wrong. Thanks for updating your question, see edit. Keep in mind this is Ask Different, not Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

```
property tmp : "~/Desktop/safarihtml.html"

set htmls to {}

tell application "Safari" to tell window 1 to if exists then ¬
    set htmls to do JavaScript ¬
        "Array.from(document" & ¬
        "          .getElementsByClassName('details'))" & ¬
        "     .map(x=>x.innerHTML);" in current tab

repeat with html in htmls
    newTabWithHTML(html)
end repeat

on newTabWithHTML(html)
    local html

    set furl to URL of tmpfile()

    set eof of (tmpfile() as alias) to 0
    write html to (tmpfile() as alias) as «class utf8»

    tell application "Safari" to tell ¬
        (a reference to window 1)
        if not (exists) then make new document

        set current tab to make new ¬
            tab with properties ¬
            {URL:furl}

        repeat until name of current tab ¬
            ≠ "Untitled"
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell

    delete tmpfile()
end newTabWithHTML


on tmpfile()
    tell application "System Events"
        set f to a reference to the file tmp
        if not (exists f) then (make new file ¬
            with properties {name:tmp})

        return f
    end tell
end tmpfile
```